# accessing info from an API and displaying in h1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I have an API array I am practicing with. Below is one object from the array called `users`. I know in order to access the properties such as the `firstName` I simply write `<h1> {users.firstName} </h1>`. However, I am trying to display the `address` property within the "address" object.  I thought it would be `<h1> {users.address.address} </h1>` but that isn't correct.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "Terry",
    "lastName": "Medhurst",
    "maidenName": "Smitham",
    "age": 50,
    "gender": "male",
    "email": "atuny0@sohu.com",
    "phone": "+63 791 675 8914",
    "username": "atuny0",
    "password": "9uQFF1Lh",
    "birthDate": "2000-12-25",
    "image": "https://robohash.org/hicveldicta.png",
    "bloodGroup": "A−",
    "height": 189,
    "weight": 75.4,
    "eyeColor": "Green",
    "hair": {
        "color": "Black",
        "type": "Strands"
    },
    "domain": "slashdot.org",
    "ip": "117.29.86.254",
    "address": {
        "address": "1745 T Street Southeast",
        "city": "Washington",
        "coordinates": {
            "lat": 38.867033,
            "lng": -76.979235
        },
        "postalCode": "20020",
        "state": "DC"
    },
    "macAddress": "13:69:BA:56:A3:74",
    "university": "Capitol University",
    "bank": {
        "cardExpire": "06/22",
        "cardNumber": "50380955204220685",
        "cardType": "maestro",
        "currency": "Peso",
        "iban": "NO17 0695 2754 967"
    },
    "company": {
        "address": {
            "address": "629 Debbie Drive",
            "city": "Nashville",
            "coordinates": {
                "lat": 36.208114,
                "lng": -86.58621199999999
            },
            "postalCode": "37076",
            "state": "TN"
        },
        "department": "Marketing",
        "name": "Blanda-O'Keefe",
        "title": "Help Desk Operator"
    },
    "ein": "20-9487066",
    "ssn": "661-64-2976",
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.702.0 Safari/534.24"
}
```

Comment: If the example contains real data, please delete and re-post your question with a fictional example. (Editing leaves a trail in the edit history.)

Comment: it's a dummy api I am practicing with

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely not looping over the array. To get the user's address, you need to get every object in the `users` array, then you can run `.address.address` on each of those objects. See the snippet below:

```js
const users = [{
  "id": 1,
  "firstName": "Terry",
  "lastName": "Medhurst",
  "maidenName": "Smitham",
  "age": 50,
  "gender": "male",
  "email": "atuny0@sohu.com",
  "phone": "+63 791 675 8914",
  "username": "atuny0",
  "password": "9uQFF1Lh",
  "birthDate": "2000-12-25",
  "image": "https://robohash.org/hicveldicta.png",
  "bloodGroup": "A−",
  "height": 189,
  "weight": 75.4,
  "eyeColor": "Green",
  "hair": {
    "color": "Black",
    "type": "Strands"
  },
  "domain": "slashdot.org",
  "ip": "117.29.86.254",
  "address": {
    "address": "1745 T Street Southeast",
    "city": "Washington",
    "coordinates": {
      "lat": 38.867033,
      "lng": -76.979235
    },
    "postalCode": "20020",
    "state": "DC"
  },
  "macAddress": "13:69:BA:56:A3:74",
  "university": "Capitol University",
  "bank": {
    "cardExpire": "06/22",
    "cardNumber": "50380955204220685",
    "cardType": "maestro",
    "currency": "Peso",
    "iban": "NO17 0695 2754 967"
  },
  "company": {
    "address": {
      "address": "629 Debbie Drive",
      "city": "Nashville",
      "coordinates": {
        "lat": 36.208114,
        "lng": -86.58621199999999
      },
      "postalCode": "37076",
      "state": "TN"
    },
    "department": "Marketing",
    "name": "Blanda-O'Keefe",
    "title": "Help Desk Operator"
  },
  "ein": "20-9487066",
  "ssn": "661-64-2976",
  "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.702.0 Safari/534.24"
}];

function App() {
  return users.map(el => <h1>{el.address.address}</h1>);
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(<App /> , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are attempting to access the `users`object.

Verify that it is an array by using the following code: `const isUserArray = Array.isArray(users);`

If the result is `true`, use a loop, such as `users.map(user => <h1>{user.address.address}</h1>)`, to iterate through the array and access the `address` property of each `user`"